# How can I run the interval on my webpage only once? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="textArea" name='textArea' maxlength="250" style="resize:none" placeholder=""></textarea>
<small>
    <span id="counter"></span>
</small>
```

and a jquery binded to this:

```
$('#textArea').bind('input propertychange', function () {
    display30Seconds();
});


function display30Seconds() {
    var validTime = 30000;
    counterInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#counter').html(validTime / 1000);
        validTime = validTime - 1000;
    }, 1000);
}
```

I want a simple effect - when user starts typing in the text area, he sees the counter going down from 30 to 0. When the counter goes down to zero I want to display an alert and disable text area. So far it works bad, because each time user types anything in text area - then we start another counters and they overlay. How can I fix it?
http://jsfiddle.net/jf4ea4nx/

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: You mean restart timer? Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jf4ea4nx/1/)

Comment: @Tushar that's great! and how can I disable the textarea when the time's up? Can you please post it as an aswer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've added answer below, check if this is what you want or [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jf4ea4nx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a simple effect - when user starts typing in the text area, he sees the counter going down from 30 to 0. When the counter goes down to zero I want to display an alert and disable text area.

Check the comments in the code below

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/jf4ea4nx/2/)

```js
$('#textArea').on('input propertychange', display30Seconds);

// Define the variable
var interval;

function display30Seconds() {
  var validTime = 3000; // Changed for Demo purpose

  // If timer not already started
  if (!interval) {
    // Save the interval id
    interval = setInterval(function() {

      $('#counter').html(validTime / 1000);
      validTime = validTime - 1000;

      // When timer reaches zero
      if (validTime < 0) {
        // Clear the interval
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert('Time Up!');

        // Disable textarea
        $('#textArea').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="textArea" name='textArea' maxlength="250" style="resize:none" placeholder=""></textarea>
<small><span id="counter"></span></small>
```

Comment: perfect, really clear explanation, thank you very much!

Comment: @user3766930 Welcome! Glad to help

Comment: I unfortunately approached another blocking point while using your code, could you help me with it at some point? I started a thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435439/how-can-i-depend-on-the-interval-that-i-just-cleared-in-jquery Thanks!