# How can I depend on the interval that I just cleared in jquery?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

It's a follow up to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430608/3766930
Basically I have a text area and when user starts typing in sth, the counter starts going down from 3 to 0. when it reaches 0 it gets disabled.

Now I want to add a feature of starting over - when user clicks the link `start over`, text area goes enabled again and user has 3 seconds (again) to perform the input.

I modified the jquery script:

```
$('#textArea').on('input propertychange', display30Seconds);

var interval;

function display30Seconds() {
    var validTime = 3000;

    if (!interval)
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#counter').html(validTime / 1000);
        validTime = validTime - 1000;

        if (validTime < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert('Time Up!');
            $('#textArea').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#counter').html('<a href="#" id="counterIsDone">start over</a>');

            $('#counterIsDone').on('click', function(){
                $('#textArea').prop('disabled', false);
                display30Seconds();
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

but I see that I cannot call the method `display30Seconds();` again. Or rather I can, but the interval is not set again. How can I fix it?
Seems like I'm not entering the code inside

```
 if (!interval)
```

because the interval is not visible any more after clearing it (?). So I thought about moving the `var interval;` into the body of the method `function display30Seconds() {`, but that doesn't bring the expected effect. Is there a way of fixing it?

Here is my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jf4ea4nx/3/

Comment: I'd recommend using a setTimeout instead of a setInterval - just have the seTimeout call itself once every second

Comment: `clearInterval` does not remove the value from the passed variable, so `interval` is going to still have whatever timer id it was assigned so `if(!interval)` is always going to evaluate to false

Comment: FYI: `setInterval`/`clearInterval` has nothing to do with jQueery - you haven't modified a jQueery script, you've modified javascript that happens to us jQueery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `interval=null` after the `clearInterval()` call.

What seems to confuse you is the semantics of `clearInterval(interval)`. As Patrick Evans points out in his comment, it will not set `interval` to a value that evaluates to `false` in a condition.

To make it completely clear you could use a boolean variable such as `countdownRunning` in addition to the `interval` variable to keep track of whether the countdown is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#textArea').on('input propertychange', display30Seconds);

var interval=false;

function display30Seconds() {
    var validTime = 3000;
    if (!interval)
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('#counter').html(validTime / 1000);
        validTime = validTime - 1000;

        if (validTime < 0) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert('Time Up!');
            $('#textArea').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#counter').html('<a href="#" id="counterIsDone">start over</a>');
         $(document).on('click','#counterIsDone', function(){
                $('#textArea').prop('disabled', false);
                display30Seconds();
            });
          interval=false; 
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code by using a conditional recursive call to to your iterative function instead - each call has a one second delay, which makes it slightly more intuitive to use (think of each call as one tick):

```
var seconds = 3;
$('#textArea').on('input propertychange', setTimeout(timeout.bind(null, seconds), 1000));

function timeout (iterations) {
        $('#counter').html(iterations);
        if (iterations === 0) {
            alert('Time Up!');
            $('#textArea').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#counter').html('<a href="#" id="counterIsDone">start over</a>');

            $('#counterIsDone').on('click', function(){
                $('#textArea').prop('disabled', false);
                timeout(seconds);
            });
        }
        else {            
            setTimeout(timeout.bind(null, --iterations), 1000);
        }
}
```

The `bind` function simply binds the arguments of the `bind` function to the arguments of the `timeout` call - the first argument to the bind function declares its `this` scope; but don't worry about that too much.

You can modify the duration of the timer by changing the `seconds` var. Hope this helps :)